# Add laravel component javascript code at end of page

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I Just have a component and I want to add component script code at the bottom of main page cause it make loading page faster. how can I do this?

**point**: each script must be written on its component file.

Comment: Please provide some sample code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can write this in your parent component `@stack('scripts')`, and in your child component you can write like this `@push('scripts)`.

your child component code will be like this

```
@push('scripts')
<script src="example.js"></>
@endpush
```

it will only push the scripts to the parent component when you load the child component.

Answer (score 0):

create a blade file where you want to put all your script link. Let I have created a file inside my resource directory and named it like `javascripts.blade.php` .The file may look like this.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
window._token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
</script>



@yield('javascript')
```

notice that I put `@yield('javascript')` at the bottom. Now you can use it inside `<body></body>` tag just using `@include(javascripts)` or if you're script file is inside a folder you can use `@include(folderName.javascripts)`

Comment: so what if when I have 2 or more component in this sort.is there any way that I can write script that related to each component in its component file ?

Comment: Yes you can .Here this example is only for common uses script files. You can create individual for any components just you need to include it from your components